# Error: 1: PCDATA invalid Char value 8 when reading XML file

Tags: r, xml

I'm trying to reading an XML file which is an export of a website. When I run the following:

```
result <- xmlParse(file = "~/Desktop/export.xml")
```

I get:

```
PCDATA invalid Char value 8
PCDATA invalid Char value 1
PCDATA invalid Char value 8
PCDATA invalid Char value 1
PCDATA invalid Char value 8
PCDATA invalid Char value 1
PCDATA invalid Char value 8
PCDATA invalid Char value 1
PCDATA invalid Char value 8
PCDATA invalid Char value 1
PCDATA invalid Char value 8
PCDATA invalid Char value 1
Error: 1: PCDATA invalid Char value 8
```

Is there any way I can skip these invalid characters and read it anyway? Or do I have to somehow remove them? I simply want to parse the XML to find URLs within it containing a specific string.

Comment: You've not posted your XML, but those characters are not allowed in any XML.  Fix your data to actually be XML before trying to parse it.

Comment: How do you do what?  Post a big file?  You don't.  You post a [mcve], and it's your job to make it *minimal*.  (But, really, here your problem is clearly invalid characters, so don't bother.)    Fix your data?  Fix it at the source, or see the duplicate link.

Comment: No need to see rudeness where none exists.

Comment: See duplicate link for how to fix bad XML, including invalid characters.